# Doctrine One-to-Many Mapping with auto generated ids

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two classes `Author` and `Posts`. One author can have many posts and the `posts` table has a reference to the author by `author_id`. I would like to tell Doctrine to populate `author_id` after it obtains the auto generated id from the database. Is that possible?

```
#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'authors')]
class Author {

    #[Id]
    #[GeneratedValue]
    #[Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[OneToMany(mappedBy: 'authorId', targetEntity: Post::class, cascade: ['persist'])]
    private ?Collection $posts;

    public function __construct(Collection $posts) {
      $this->posts = $posts;
    }
}
```

```
#[Entity]
#[Table(name: 'posts')]
class Post {

    #[Id]
    #[GeneratedValue]
    #[Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[Column]
    #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: Author::class, inversedBy: 'id')]
    #[JoinColumn(name: 'author_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private ?int $authorId = null,
}
```

To save the data, I created an `ArrayCollection` of `Post`s with nulls because the data needed should be handled by Doctrine.

```
$posts = new ArrayCollection([
  new Post(null, null),
  new Post(null, null)
]);

$author = new Author(posts: $posts);

$em->persist($author);
$em->flush();
```

Thanks!

Comment: That happens automatically when you persist and flush them.  Maybe you are asking something else?  I did not check your attributes real close but I assume they came from make:entity.

Comment: It doesn't happen automatically in this case. I received an error saying that `$authorId` cannot be null before persisting while I was trying to flush the root entity.

Comment: Which is the root entity?  Having cascade on Author implies it is the root entity.  So you persist author then the posts will be automatically persisted at the same time.  Going the other direction will not work.  In any event, do an explicit `$em->persist($author)` and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Sorry about the `make:entity` suggestion.  I just noticed you are using Doctrine standalone and that you are injecting a collection of posts into the author's constructor.  That is a bit problematical perhaps.  You really need to make sure all your objects cross reference each other.  Consider updating your question with a bit of code showing how your root entity is being setup.

Comment: Yea that is not going to work.  `private ?int $authorId = null` illustrates your basic conceptual problem.  Doctrine associates objects and not ids.  So your should have something like `private ?Author $author = null;` See the difference? And it up to you to make sure the author is set for each post.  Keep reading and experimenting with [the example](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) in the docs until you understand the basics.

Comment: And you might consider installing a Symfony app and going through it's Doctrine [examples](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) as well.  It might be somewhat overwhelming but it does provide some additional development tools that come in handy.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarifications, I've already read the mapping examples but somehow I missed the object part and the error wasn't that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments the basic problem was trying to use ids to associate entities and not having them cross linked properly.  I did want to see if I could get passing an array of child elements into a constructor to work. I made a test example inside of the Symfony framework since it has been way too long since I used Doctrine standalone.  Everything should still work one the ORM is removed from the mapping namespace.

I also added a couple of properties to author/post just to make things more realistic. So this works:

```
        $author = new Author('David Weber',new ArrayCollection([
            new Post('SafeHold'),
            new Post('Honor'),
        ]));
        $this->em->persist($author);
        $this->em->flush();
```

The Post entity is pretty much unchanged except for making the $author property an Author instead of an id.

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PostRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'posts')]
class Post
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'posts')]
    private ?Author $author = null;
```

The Author gets a few tweaks to ensure the Post entity is linked to the author:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AuthorRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'authors')]
class Author
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'author', targetEntity: Post::class, cascade: ['persist'])]
    private Collection $posts;

    public function __construct(string $name, ?ArrayCollection $posts = null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
        if ($posts !== null) {
            foreach($posts as $post) {
                $this->addPost($post);
            }
        }
    }
    public function addPost(Post $post): self
    {
        if (!$this->posts->contains($post)) {
            $this->posts->add($post);
            $post->setAuthor($this); // Notice this
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

I should also perhaps point out that the entity skeletons we generated by using Symfony's `make:entity` command.  So methods like addPost are automatically added.

Enjoy